# render data from array to select option laravel

Tags: laravel

```
function getAllYears()
{ 
    $year_array = array();
    $posts_dates = Entries::orderBy( 'created_at', 'ASC' )->pluck( 'created_at' );
    $posts_dates = json_decode( $posts_dates );

    if ( ! empty( $posts_dates ) ) 
    {
        foreach ( $posts_dates as $unformatted_date )
         {
            $date = new \DateTime( $unformatted_date->date );
            $year_value = $date->format( 'Y' );
            $year_val = $date->format( 'y' );

            //$year_array[$year_val ] = $year_value;
            $year_array[] = $year_value;
         }
    } //return $year_array;
    $array = $year_array;
```

// Deleting the duplicate items
$unique_years = array_unique($array);

return view('welcome',compact($unique_years));

```
<select name="YearFrom" id="YearFrom_input"">
    <option selected="selected">Choose Year</option>
    @foreach($unique_years as $years)
        <option value='{{$years}}'> {{$years['years']}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

!!getting error!!

> compact(): Undefined variable: 2009

Comment: Please provide context on what you are attempting to do, what is each block of code supposed to do, one seems to be a template and the other seems to be logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: i want to fetch all the years from data base and render it to the usr page to allow the user to choose from the years only inserted in database

Answer (score 0):

`compact` thinks the values of your array are the variables names, because you've passed it the actual array, not the name of the variable. See http://php.net/compact for details on how `compact()` works. Instead, you need:

```
return view('welcome',compact('unique_years'));
```

That said, I hate the `compact` approach for this reason. This is much more readable:

```
return view('welcome')->with('unique_years', $unique_years);
```

Comment: is there any problem with the view section>

Comment: @AliRezaArju Do you get further errors when you fix the one I've highlighted?

Comment: yes i do here it is ---Illegal string offset 'years' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: Well, there's no such thing as `$years['years']` as far as I can tell. You probably just want to output `{{ $years }}` there.

Comment: can you help me with one more thing  $users = DB::table('entries')->select('dept')->get(); return $users;   i am getting this {"dept": "SECS"}, but i need only "SECS",distinct function is not working.what should i do

Comment: You should read and understand https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries. The distinct function has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your variabel name was incorrect in compact() - should be a string like 'variable_name' rather than $variable_name

```
function getAllYears()
{
    $year_array = array();
    $posts_dates = Entries::orderBy( 'created_at', 'ASC' )->pluck( 'created_at' );
    $posts_dates = json_decode( $posts_dates );

    if ( ! empty( $posts_dates ) )  {
        foreach ( $posts_dates as $unformatted_date ) {
            $date = new \DateTime( $unformatted_date->date );
            $year_value = $date->format( 'Y' );
            $year_val = $date->format( 'y' );

            //$year_array[$year_val ] = $year_value;
            $year_array[] = $year_value;
        }
    } //return $year_array;

    $array = $year_array;

    // Deleting the duplicate items
    $unique_years = array_unique($array);

    return view('welcome',compact('unique_years'));
}
```